# Trigger : DELETED table does not exist

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am learning SQL trigger and have read some tutorial on how to delete a row on table B when a row in table a is deleted.

I have the following trigger :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `testDB`.`test_BEFORE_DELETE` 
BEFORE DELETE ON `testDBtable` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    Delete from testDBtable2 where id = (select id from deleted);
END
```

Both testDBtable and testDBtable2 have 2 column, id and name.

When I deleted a row from testDB, I received the following error:

```
Error Code: 1146. Table 'testDB.deleted' doesn't exist  0.000 sec
```

I am using MYSQLWorkBench.

Answer (score 0):

I think `OLD.id` is the one you need instead of `select id from deleted`.

Full query:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `testDB`.`test_BEFORE_DELETE` 
BEFORE DELETE ON `testDBtable` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    Delete from testDBtable2 where id = OLD.id;
END
```

Comment: HI Luca , i tired your query , old is not recognize as a keyword.